# SES to SNS is sending Encrypted Content

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I've setup aws SES to receive emails and publish to an SNS topic. The topic then triggers a lambda event to process the email.

My issue is that the event given to the lambda has all the information but the 'content' of the email (IE: the email body) is encrypted. I do not see at any point where I had set an encryption key. I've also tried to decrypt using boto3 and passing any keys that made sense for AWS to have auto applied none of which worked.

```
client = boto3.client('kms')

response = client.decrypt(
    CiphertextBlob=content,
    KeyId='Key_id_here',
    EncryptionAlgorithm='SYMMETRIC_DEFAULT'
)
```

Comment: Encrypted or [Base64 encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)?  Can you share a small part of the email?

Comment: @stdunbar Oof It's base64.... i'm an idiot. thank you!